# Apache connection timed out received on Android Client

Tags: php, android, apache, ubuntu

We have an application, with following Platforms:

Client:-
Android

Server:-
Apache, PHP/MySql, Linux Ubuntu

There are almost 70-80 Applications(Android) running at Client End which consumes API of PHP.

Few days earlier, we have observed an issue that when few of the Clients tried to consume PHP API they have received "Connect to /XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:80 timed out" error.

But there is nothing received on Server End and server application logs / apache access logs for that request.

Note: Please keep in mind, that issue happened only in few clients not all. At the time of issue, we were able to ping server from client but unable to consume APIs.

We are assuming that there could be two things:

1. No or Low Internet Connectivity at Client End (Android).
2. Apache Server having Open Connections getting full at a time.

Our /etc/apache2/apache2.conf consists following attributes:

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5

And other mpm files under directory of /etc/apache2/mods-available

mpm_worker.conf

```
StartServers             2

MinSpareThreads      25

MaxSpareThreads      75

ThreadLimit          64

ThreadsPerChild      25

MaxRequestWorkers     150

MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
```

mpm_prefork.conf

```
StartServers             5

MinSpareServers       5

MaxSpareServers      10

MaxRequestWorkers     150

MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
```

mpm_event.conf

StartServers             2

```
MinSpareThreads      25

MaxSpareThreads      75

ThreadLimit          64

ThreadsPerChild      25

MaxRequestWorkers     150

MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
```

We have tried executing below command:

netstat -nt | grep :80 | wc -l

And got result around 180-200

Please guide us regarding connections and apache related configurations. And what was the issue which caused "Connection timed out" at specific time and its working fine now. But we are unable to identify root cause of the issue happened.

Comment: that info alone is not enough, and besides you are saying there is nothing on the server logs, so other than networking issue, with the info you provide, aside from a networking issue hardly anything could be suggested. Re-check server error.log for maxclients errors or similar, present your mpm setup, and if you are sure there is no problems in the load at the httpd server, then review your network.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, can you please Guide what kind of more info required apart from the things you asked. Yes I have checked error.log and access.log. there is nothing on that time. But can you please guide what do you mean by max client errors? And for mpm setup, I will share all conf files. That's the problem I am not 100% sure that there is no problem in the load at the httpd server, want guidance to check.

Comment: Have added code from MPM files and other information too, please go through it again. Thanks!

Comment: @ezra-s, one more question please that should I put "KeepAlive" Off as my server mostly depends on API. Web Portal also run but not much.

Comment: but.. which mpm of those three are you using? Only one applies. If you are with prefork, the low ammount of minimum childs could explain timeouts, but since you say there are no erros in logs...

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just checked with command "apachectl -V | grep -i mpm". Yes server is using prefork MPM. Please guide the better values or calculations for mpm_prefork.conf file.